# Steel tensile strength explanation needed

Tags: forces, stress-strain, metals

Can someone explain to me, how Steel tensile strength works?
Lets take "S355" for an example.

S355 means, its tensile strength is 355 N/mm2. Which means when i place 355N worth of load to an 1mm2 area, it will deform/go to state which steel doent withstand the force anymore also even break.

So basically this is maximum capability to withstand FORCE to an AREA. Right?

Now i have S355 sheet metal with thickness of 1mm and S355 sheet metal with thickness of 10mm.

Obviously, the 10mm sheet metal is stronger because its thicker, right.
But they both have 355MPA of tensile strength.

Now what i don't understand, how can they both be 355MPA but when changing thickness their ability to withstand force is increased. Meaning if i apply 355N of force to 1 mm2 area, the 1mm thickness sheet metal breaks but the 10mm dont.

How is this 355MPA taken/calculated? How does it work exactly?

Comment: The whole point is to have a parameter independent of the cross sectional area…

Answer (score 1):

the strength rating is based on *per unit of cross sectional area*. If you double the thickness of a test sample, you have doubled its cross-sectional area. this means the *load* is now distributed over *twice* the area, making it more capable of withstanding the load without yielding.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically this is maximum capability to withstand FORCE to an AREA. Right?

Yes, but no.

Your biggest source of confusion and probably the reason you got downvotes is that your problem setup is sloppy.

You have failed to specify the type and direction of the force you are applying to your plate. Tensile strength is only one type of strength.  Tensile force is only one type of force that can be applied. Forces can be applied in more than one direction.

Tensile strength is for TENSILE forces only. Such as the strength of a rope being pulled (not pushed, not twisted, not bent, not sheared like if you cut it with scissors) being determined by cross-sectional area (aka how thick the rope is). So if the rope is a solid, unstranded mass of S355 steel, which is basically a rod with a $1mm^2$ cross section. Then if $355N/mm^2$ is the ultimate tensile strength it should take $355N$ of pull to break it. If $355N/mm^2$ is the yield tensile strength then that is the minimum pull force it would take to permanently deform (in this case stretch) the rope.

Now is this the scenario you have for your plate? It could be, but I don't know because you did not say what direction you are applying forces in. But if it is not then tensile strength is either the wrong strength number to use, or not the only number you need to use.

You use vague phrases like "*stronger because its thicker*" and "*if I apply 355N of force to 1 mm2 area, the 1mm thickness sheet metal breaks but the 10mm dont.*" In what direction? You speak as though there is only one direction in which the force can be applied. You can't be sloppy setting things up.

Are you trying to pull the plate apart? If so, in what axis? If pulling perpendicular the face of the plate (i.e. to make two plates of the same area but half the thickness), then increasing thickness does not increase strength at all, but increasing plate area will because that's the cross-section you are pulling on. If pulling to make two pieces of half the area (i.e. how you might normally pull, not tear...tearing different, a sheet of paper in two) then increasing thickness does increase the strength.

Or are you trying to bend the plate? In what direction (i.e. like normally folding a piece of paper? or bending edge-to-edge so the entire sheet stays in the same plane at all times?) Bending is not purely tensile. Bending is a combination of tensile on one side and compression on the other so you cannot only use tensile strength. Cross-section is also innsufficient here...the geometric parameter used is called the second moment of inertia. Second moment of inertia also depends on direction and the direction used must match the direction the bending is in. Look up why tubes and I-beams are almost as stiff and strong (which themselves are two distinct concepts, don't mix them up) when bent along their length  as solid rods despite being much less weight.

Or are you compressing the plate? Well that's not tensile at all so you can't use tensile strength.

Comment: Hello thank you. You cleared alot things up here and i now feel incredibility dumb. I should have formed the question better and now i do realized, that i was talking about Compression. Reason i said Tensile Strength was because all these Steels are sold with their Tensile Strength grades, not with their compression grades. To reformulate my question is if i apply load/hit with a hammer  greater than Sheet of S355 metal can handle. It should deform both cases 1mm and 10mm thickness (load/hit is the same)? Because its all related to cross sectional area? Thanks

Comment: @wtknow Yeah. Compression is kind of tricky because a lot of the compression failures in the real world are due to imperfections in the material causing buckling and localized points which then spread. This can also make figuring out bending strength tricky since bending involves compression. A lot of materials have a compression strength that is lower than their tensile strength which means that is the limiting factor, so in that cause when using the second moment of inertia of a geometry in equations, the compression strength is used since that will give before the tensile strength does.

Comment: @wtknow But hitting with a hammer is yet another kind of strength called impact strength since it is more about how much energy the material can absorb. This is opposed to slowly applying a continuous force to bend the object. A piece of glass for instance can be shattered by a shallow tap that when the depth of that tap is less than a deformation the glass could otherwise withstand when being applied by a gradual force. And yet another kind of strength is how much the material deforms around where the hammer hit it due to localized pressure (which is called hardness).